# Replace append text before last occurrence of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to construct a RegExp to append text before the last occurrence of the string, but in the current approach, the replaced `.html` part is lost. Can you please suggest how can it be fixed?

```js
const URL = 'www.website.com/path/fileName.html'
const urlPrefix = '.prefix1.prefix2'
const newURL = URL.replace(/.html(^)*$/, `${urlPrefix}$1`)

// Expected output www.website.com/path/fileName.prefix1.prefix2.html
console.log(newURL)
```

Comment: `(^)*` is redundant.  The backreference to whole match is `$&`, not `$1`. Use ``URL.replace(/\.html$/, `${urlPrefix}$&`)``. And it seems you do not need the last occurrence of `.html`, but `.html` that is at the end of string, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(^)*` is redundant in your regex because it matches *start of string zero or more times*, which is rather meaningless.

The backreference to whole match is `$&`, not `$1`, the `$1` is empty in your case since `(^)*` simply captures an empty string.

You can use

```
URL.replace(/\.html$/, `${urlPrefix}$&`)
```

Note the escaped dot, else, `.` matches any char but line break chars.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const URL = 'www.website.com/path/fileName.html'
const urlPrefix = '.prefix1.prefix2'
const newURL = URL.replace(/\.html$/, `${urlPrefix}$&`)
console.log(newURL)
// => www.website.com/path/fileName.prefix1.prefix2.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer bro. You can add as many prefixes in this, *just you need to push it in the `array`*. First, we `split` the `URL` into an `array` of strings. Then, we pop out the last index string from that `array` that will be the `initial last prefix`. Then, we can push as many prefixes into the `array`. Finally, we will push the `initial last prefix` to the same `array` and `join` the `array` of strings with `Dot(.)` and we will get the desired output string.

```js
const URL = "www.website.com/path/fileName.html";
const arr = URL.split("."); // output: ["www","website","com/path/fileName","html"]

const lastprefix = arr.pop(); // output: html

arr.push("prefix1"); // output: ["www","website","com/path/fileName","prefix1"]
arr.push("prefix2"); // output: ["www","website","com/path/fileName","prefix1","prefix2"]
arr.push(lastprefix); // output: ["www","website","com/path/fileName","prefix1","prefix2","html"]

const newURL = arr.join("."); // output: www.website.com/path/fileName.prefix1.prefix2.html

// Expected output www.website.com/path/fileName.prefix1.prefix2.html
console.log(newURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `.html` part too.

```js
const URL = 'www.website.com/path/fileName.html'
const urlPrefix = '.prefix1.prefix2'
const newURL = URL.replace(/.html(^)*$/, `${urlPrefix}$1.html`)

// Expected output www.website.com/path/fileName.prefix1.prefix2.html
console.log(newURL)
```